# How to show my site in full screen on mobile (iphone)

Tags: css

how i can make my website width in full screen not bigger than screen i use this code

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, inittial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:730px)" href="css/style_small.css" />
    <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 730px)" href="css/style_small.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

and the css code

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
background: #fff url(../images/Bbg.jpg) 0px 0px;
width:100%;
}

.adlogo {
    background-image: url(../images/lbg.png);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: #999 solid 1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.adlogo .ads img {
    float:left;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 50px;
}

.adlogo .logo img {
    float:right;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-right: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
}

.top {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #1d1d1d;
    border-bottom: #2f2f2f solid 2px;
}

.top .menu1{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    max-width:730px;
}

.hmenu {
    background: url(../images/lbg.png);
    height: 200px;
}

.hmenu .menu2 {
    width:95%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.hmenu .menu2 ul {
    padding:0px;
    width:185px;
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:95%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.hmenu .menu2 ul li{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    color: #a6abc5;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 9px;
    border:1px solid #21b8ff;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.hmenu .menu2 ul li a{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

.hmenu .menu2 ul li:hover{
    color:#636363;
    background: #21b8ff;
}
```

but when i open the webiste in my phone i get that the website is not 100% on screen i get that the website is bigger than the mobile screen

Comment: You misspelled the `width` attribute in your viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` in your css to set different styles and sizes like width and height for different device sizes. with css below i'm just giving you and example. you don't have to place all the divs inside the `@media`. just place those you will need for smaller screens.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 730px) {
    body {
    background: #fff url(../images/Bbg.jpg) 0px 0px;
    width:100%;
  }

  .adlogo {
    background-image: url(../images/lbg.png);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: #999 solid 1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
 }

  .adlogo .ads img {
    float:left;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 50px;
}

  .adlogo .logo img {
    float:right;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-right: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```